# Prerequisites to read Katz's Gauss Sums, Kloosterman Sums, and Monodromy Groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, exponential-sums

What is the minimal background one must have to read Katz's *Gauss Sums, Kloosterman Sums, and Monodromy Groups*?